# How i get a value from $.get in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, element, domparser

i have a function

```
 function cauta_pe_google(numele) {
    var result;
    var ficus;
    $.get(numele, function(data) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
    var rezultlate_vo = doc.getElementsByClassName("product_img small_img")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[0];

    if(rezultlate_vo) {
          try {
              result = rezultlate_vo.getAttribute("img-src");
          }  catch (error){
            alert(error);
         }
    } else {
        result = "nimic";
    }
}).done(function() {
    ficus = result;
  alert (ficus); //here it's ok i get the image 
    return ficus;

  });
  alert (ficus); //here i get undefined error
 //return ficus;
}
```

I tried to get an image from a link, at the first alert(ficus) I get the image result fine (http://image.jpg) but on the return (second alert) i have an undefined result, how i can extract that variable to use it in other places? Not only in the get function?
Thanks!

Comment: because of `return ficus;` when you returned function execution ended and variable destroyed (also called variable scope)

Comment: @Anant well, no, the var still existed at that point.

Comment: @KevinB then why undefined?

Comment: @Anant Because it hasn't been given a value yet.

Comment: `ficus = result;alert (ficus); //here it's ok i get the image `

Comment: @Anant that happens some time in the future, long after the alert at the end. If it were wrapped in a setTimeout longer than the duration of the ajax request, it would have a value.